# fibre of a fibration is homotopy equivalent to its homotopy fibre

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Can someone give me a hint on proving that the fibre of a fibration $f: Y \to X$ is homotopy equivalent to its homotopy fibre $Y \times_X X^I$?

Comment: Not a hint, but a couple of arguments and references can be found [in this MO-thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53729/the-fiber-of-a-serre-fibration).

Comment: Thanks, I already found this. But I don't want the complete argument.

Comment: The first step would be to construct a continuous function from one to the other.  There appears to be a good choice *from* the fibre *to* the homotopy fibre.

Answer (score 2):

The homotopy fiber of a map is only defined up to homotopy equivalence. I think this is a crucial point to your question.
One model for it is given by the following construction.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be any map. Then we may factor it as a homotopy equivalence followed by a fibration, ie $X \to Z \to Y$, call the last map $g: Z \to Y$ which is a fibration. Now one model for the homotopy fiber of $f$ is just the honest fiber of the map $g$.
In the case that $f$ itself is a fibration one may choose the obvious factorization to see that its fiber is one model for a homotopy fiber.

But since you asked for this very explicit model, at least assuming that all spaces are CW complexes, here is a brief idea of an argument. Comparing the long exact sequences of the fibration $f$ and the long exact sequence associated to the homotopy fiber of $f$ together with the "good choice" of a map from the fiber to the homotopy fiber and a 5 Lemma argument shows that fiber and homotopy fiber are weakly equivalent. By Whitehead then they are also homotopy equivalent.
By the good choice I mean the following:
A map from the fiber $F$ to $Y\times_{X} X^{I}$ is given by compatible maps
$F \to Y$ which you choose to be the inclusion and $F to X^{I}$ which can be chosen as the constant map at the basepoint of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the main theorem in

R. Brown and P.R. Heath, "Coglueing homotopy equivalences", Math.Z. 113 (1970) 313-325,

available [here](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brown-heath.pdf), which gives conditions for a pullback of homotopy equivalences to be a homotopy equivalence. A fibre is the pullback over a point. One uses the fact that any map, which in this instance is  a fibration, factors through a homotopy equivalence and a fibration, as given by mland. The theorem is the dual of the gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences, which can be found in [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uktopgpds.html), T&G, and has a dual proof. This proof gives also good control over the homotopies involved: see 7.4.2 (Addendum).  The operation used is called "transport" in tom Dieck's book "Algebraic Topology", p.107 (EMS, 2008). It generalises the operation of the fundamental groupoid on higher homotopy groups.

A use of this "transport" in the fibration situation  is also suggested in my sketch answer to [this mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208413/pull-back-of-a-fibration-along-a-homotopy-equivalence-and-homotopy-classes-of-se?rq=1) question.